Getting "Some of these settings are hidden or managed by your organization" after malware [Solved]

I had malware and now I'm getting:
"Some of these settings are hidden or managed by your organization" after malware
On the App screen in Windows under settings. I had this in Chrome and Edge and was able to get rid of them, but I don't know how to get rid of this one. I am using Windows 10 home, so I don't have the group policy editor.
I believe I need to remove registry keys, but I don't know which ones or where.
I'm not sure if this message hurts anything, since malware bytes and Avast killed the underlying malware, but I would like to remove it if I can.
Deleting "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\SmartScreen" fixed it! I'm not sure what those key/values did, because the one value was just a number and the other one was just the word Anywhere. The other ones in Chome and Edge actually contained like urls and file paths.
Thanks guys!

Does this answer your question? How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?

"Some of these settings are hidden or managed by your organization" is most often displayed when you have a relevant feature or option disabled.  Provide a screenshot of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\SmartScreen by editing your question

Try running wsreset.exe as an Administrator.

The Group Policy settings are just Registry entries, so they can be changed using Regedit.

Press Windows, type rege, and select Regedit.

Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\SmartScreen.

There are two values in that key,

ConfigureAppInstallControl, currently set to Anywhere
ConfigureAppInstallControlEnabled, currently set to zero.

Those values may be deleted , or even the whole key, SmartScreen.


That should return control of Apps & Features to you.
Caveat: Despite scanning with two anti-malware suites, there could still be remnants of that malware left, such as a backdoor. Consider scanning with yet another tool (check that the utility has a good reputation), and also reinstalling Windows, keeping files.
